# How can I close the bottom of a cup?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I´m learning blender now and I was practicing modelling a cup but when I got almost to the end of it I realized it was botomless. I guess I did that when I was trying to fix the subdivision surface that was curving the bottom too. Is there a way I can close it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Select the bottom loop and do Grid fill. Else extrude, press the escape key and scale inwards. Repeat extrusions and finally merge vertices at the center to close.

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit Mode* select the bottom edge by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>.

Press <kbd>F</kbd> to make a face.